# Numerical solution of a system of differential equations with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods

I am working on modelling the infection rate of a disease based on some data. The problem has now come down to solving a system of linear first order differential equations with variable coefficients. I was looking for ways to solve this system of equations numerically and could not find anything satisfactory. (Also, I'm coding in python and the scipy library solvers have proved to be unwieldy for my purposes).

The problem in greater detail:

$$ \dfrac{\mathrm{d}Y}{\mathrm{d}t} = f(Y, t, \Theta)$$

Where $Y$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{12}$, $\ t$ is the discrete time vector in $\mathbb{Z}^ n$ and $\Theta$ is a vector of parameters in $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times n} \\ $.

So to summarise, the coefficients of the function $\ f $ are based on the values of the three parameters $\Theta$ which is a matrix and the values of each of the parameters changes over the time instances. The parameters' explicit representations with respect to time are unknown. I am stuck here as I am unable to find a numerical method which could yield a satisfactory solution for this problem. Can someone suggest methods which tackle similar problems? Thanks.

**Edit:** Based on a comment, I'm adding a few of the equations that are a part of the system:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}y_1}{\mathrm{d}t} = -\beta(t) \cdot i(t) \cdot y_1 + \beta(t) \cdot s(t) \cdot y_5 + \kappa \cdot y_9  - s(t) \cdot i(t) \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}y_2}{\mathrm{d}t}  = -\beta(t) \cdot i(t) \cdot y_2 + \beta(t) \cdot s(t) \cdot y_6 + \kappa \cdot y_{10} \qquad \qquad \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}y_1}{\mathrm{d}t} = -\beta(t) \cdot i(t) \cdot y_3 + \beta(t) \cdot s(t) \cdot y_7 + \kappa \cdot y_{11} \qquad \qquad   \\$$

So for the matrix $\Theta$, the $t^{th}$ row could be thought of as the vector: $[\beta(t), s(t), i(t)]$. As the size of the time domain is $n$ the matrix would have $n$ columns. $\kappa$ is a constant.

Comment: Could you write out the first two or three ODEs explicitly? I'm not sure what you mean when you say 'the values of the four parameters $\Theta$ which is a matrix'. Also, $\Theta = \Theta (t)$?

Comment: @Mattos I've added some more details. Hope that helps. I changed it to three parameters as i noticed that one is a constant.

Comment: If you know the form of $\beta(t), i(t)$ and $s(t)$ then this is just a system of coupled ODEs with non-constant coefficients. In which case, why not just use an explicit RK4 or something else easy to implement?

Comment: @Mattos That's the problem. The form of $\beta(t), i(t)$ and $s(t)$ are what  i'm trying to model and I only have simulated values for these.

Comment: Traditionally, $i$ denotes the fraction of the population which is immune, and $s$ denotes the fraction of the population which is susceptible. Why are these functions not part of the system of differential equations? In any case, will it be enough to approximate $i$, $s$ and $\beta$ using splines. Then you can certainly compute integrate your original equations using your favorite solver. What can be said about the sign of the functions $y_i$, i.e., are they always of fixed sign? What is your error tolerance? Which technique do you plan to use?